# Formatting php output correctly

Tags: php, arrays, string, unity-game-engine, arangodb

i've did some research but i can't find what i am looking for.
I am far from a PHP expert but i think i am trying to do something fairly simple.

In Unity3D i want to receive a couple of values from the PHP output which i get doing a post request.

The output is from an arangoDB and looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(ArangoDBClient\Document)#9 (9) {
    ["_id":protected]=>
    string(16) "Producten/140368"
    ["_key":protected]=>
    string(6) "140368"
    ["_rev":protected]=>
    string(11) "_WMOJhJe--_"
    ["_values":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      ["Naam Product"]=>
      string(9) "Naam-Foo2"
      ["Categorie Product"]=>
      string(14) "Categorie-Foo2"
      ["Discipline Product"]=>
      string(15) "Discipline-Foo2"
    }
    ["_changed":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_isNew":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_doValidate":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_hiddenAttributes":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_ignoreHiddenAttributes":protected]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

I am only interested in this part:

```
["Naam Product"]=>
      string(9) "Naam-Foo2"
      ["Categorie Product"]=>
      string(14) "Categorie-Foo2"
      ["Discipline Product"]=>
      string(15) "Discipline-Foo2"
```

Best case scenario it is formatted like this:

```
Naam Product: Naam-Foo2;
Categorie Product: Categorie-Foo2;
Discipline Product: Discipline-Foo2;
```

How do i filter this information so i get a clean string of data when i read it out in Unity?

Any advice on this? Thnx in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, It's better to send `JSON` data from the server to client. Just Add [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library to your `Unity3D` project. Then you can easily deserialize your recieved json string into a C# object. Here is a simple example:

```
string jsonString = "Your json string";

var deserializedObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YOUR_POCO_OBJECT>(jsonString);
```

Now you can use `deserializedObject` fields

---

Here is a simple C# Console Application example

```
namespace JsonDEMO
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Discipline { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = "{ 'Name': 'Naam-Foo2','Category': 'Categorie-Foo2','Discipline': 'Discipline-Foo2'}";

            var deserializedObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(jsonString);

            System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Name);
            System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Category);
            System.Console.WriteLine(deserializedObject.Discipline);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i think you're right. I've read about it but i thought before i can send a json string from my php i have to clean it a bit to the bits and pieces i need? Because now i have 1 simple array which i can convert to json and then receive as json in unity i assume. At least that's what i am trying to do now :)

i've added  echo json_encode($interested_array); and now i have clean json as output, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `getAll` method:

```
$interested_array = $filter[0]->getAll();
print_r($interested_array);
```

Comment: It gives me this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type ArangoDBClient\Cursor as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\ArangoTest\index.php:62 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ArangoTest\index.php on line 62

I removed the [] and now it outputs it already a little cleaner! it's seems like its an array in an array. how do you filter that?